# Pasando datos $.post()jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Estoy pasando un formulario por post a js junto con jquey el ese formulario tiene una lista generada por una consulta a mysql, pero como se muestra a continuacion yo envio por medio de dos inputs de vectores pacientes[] y meses[] pero no me guarda la lista completa

```
<form id="planificacion-form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(''); ?>" method="post">
   <table class="table  table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Acción</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>PACIENTES</th>
                <th>CÉDULA</th>
                <th>CELULAR</th>
                <th>TELEFONO</th>
                <th>CANT MESES</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($pacientes_planificaciones as $key => $value) {  ?>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="<?= $value->ID ?>" name="pacientes[]" checked>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $value->ID; ?>
                    </td>
                   
                    <td>
                       <?php echo $value->NOMBRE . " " . $APELLIDO; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $value->CEDULA; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $value->TELEFONO; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $value->CELULAR; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $value->CANT_MESES; ?> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="meses[]"  value="<?php echo $value->CANT_MESES; ?>">
                    </td>
                     
                       <!--  -->
                      
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

```
$("#planificacion-form").on("submit", function () {
event.preventDefault();

var NombrePlanificacion = $("#NombrePlanificacion").val();
var Guion = $("#guion").val();
var fecha_inicio = $("#fecha_inicio").val();
var fecha_fin = $("#fecha_fin").val();
var val = [];
var meses =  [];
var planificacion_tipo = $("#planificacion_tipo").val();
var cantidad_meses = $("#cantidad_meses").val();
var producto_id = $("#producto_id").val();
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
    val[i] = $(this).val();
});
$("input[name*='meses']").each(function (i) {
    meses[i] = $(this).val();
});
  /*console.log(meses);*/ 

if (val.length > 0) {
    $('.mensaje').empty();

    $.post('api_crear_plan.php', {
        planificacion_tipo: planificacion_tipo,
        cantidad_meses: cantidad_meses,
        producto_id: producto_id,
        NombrePlanificacion: NombrePlanificacion,
        Guion: Guion,
        fecha_inicio: fecha_inicio,
        fecha_fin: fecha_fin,
        pacientes_ids: val,
        meses: meses
    }, function (data) {


        $('.mensaje').html('<div class="alert alert-success mt-4">Planificación registrada exitosamente </div>');



    });
} else {
    $('.mensaje').empty();
    $('.mensaje').html('<div class="alert alert-danger mt-4">No hay pacientes para registrar en la planificación </div>');
}
```

})

y de ahi por post al siguiente archivo  para crear la misma tabla pero en mysql a
un api_crear_plan.php

```
$planifiaciones = new PlanificacionController();

// user validation
require_once 'controllers/UsuarioController.php';
$usuario = new UsuarioController();
$usuario->verifyUserLogin();

// Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(0);
// Report all errors
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    /*   */
    // capturar datos
    $planificacion_tipo = $_POST['planificacion_tipo'];
    $cantidad_meses = $_POST['cantidad_meses'];
    $producto_id = $_POST['producto_id'];
    $NombrePlanificacion = $_POST['NombrePlanificacion'];
    $Guion = $_POST['Guion'];
    $fecha_inicio = $_POST['fecha_inicio'];
    $fecha_fin = $_POST['fecha_fin'];
    $pacientes_ids = $_POST['pacientes_ids'];
    $meses = $_POST['meses'];
    
    $array_data = array("planificacion_tipo" => $planificacion_tipo, "producto_id" => $producto_id, "NombrePlanificacion" => $NombrePlanificacion, "Guion" => $Guion, "fecha_inicio" => $fecha_inicio, "fecha_fin" => $fecha_fin, "pacientes_ids" => $pacientes_ids, "meses" => $meses);
    $mensaje = $planifiaciones->crearplan($array_data);
    print_r($mensaje);
```

esto lo resive el siguiente metodo.

```
public function crearplan($array_data)
{

    $planificacion = new Planificacion();
    $planificacion->setNombre($array_data["NombrePlanificacion"]);
    $planificacion->setGuion($array_data["Guion"]);
    $fecha_creacion = date("Y-m-d");
    $planificacion->setPlanificacion_tipo_id($array_data["planificacion_tipo"]);
    $planificacion->setProducto_id($array_data["producto_id"]);
    $planificacion->setFecha_creacion($fecha_creacion);
    $planificacion->setFecha_inicial($array_data["fecha_inicio"]);
    $planificacion->setFecha_final($array_data["fecha_fin"]);
    $planificacion->setPacientes($array_data["pacientes_ids"]);
    $planificacion->setMeses($array_data["meses"]);

    $result_array_pacientes = [];
    $result_planificacion_id =  $planificacion->crear_planificacion();
    foreach ($array_data["pacientes_ids"] as $key => $value) {
        # code...
        
        $array_aux = array($value, 0, $result_planificacion_id, $array_data["meses"][$key]);
        array_push($result_array_pacientes, $array_aux);
    }
    $planificacion->setPacientes($result_array_pacientes);

    $result_pacientes_ids = $planificacion->crear_planificacion_pacientes($result_planificacion_id);

    return $result_pacientes_ids;
}
```

Cuando llega a api_crear_plan.php los datos pareciera que no estuvieran completos no se si es que tiene un limite el uso de $.post()

Comment: Saludos. TE sugiero amplies más; el *pareciera que no estuvieran completos* no me dice mucho que ocurre; te comento lo siguiente (a salvedad por resumir o no sea significativo lo omitieras) en `$("#planificacion-form").on("submit", [...]);` tanto `planificacion_tipo`, `cantidad_meses` y `producto_id` (por mencionar algunos) no hay donde esten (ni son son input -text, hidden...-, textarea o algun elemento) los envias pero ni idea donde se asignan o están; amplia o especifica que **no esta completo**.

Comment: osea el formulario solo envia dos inputs de array y lo recoge el archivo de js cuando al formulario se le da submit 
$("#planificacion-form").on("submit",

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el error era de MAX_INPUT_VARS del archivo php.ini y httpd.conf debido a que estaba pasando mas de 1000 mil datos por decirlo de alguna manera, pero no se si esto afecte en un servidor remoto

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).